# after inserting a new template whole website crashed and showing this error

Tags: wordpress

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_direction() on null in /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/breakpoints/manager.php:233 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/stylesheet.php(326): Elementor\Core\Breakpoints\Manager->get_device_min_breakpoint('laptop') #1 /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/stylesheet.php(359): Elementor\Stylesheet->hash_to_query(Array) #2 [internal function]: Elementor\Stylesheet->Elementor{closure}('max_mobile', 'min_laptop') #3 /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/stylesheet.php(384): uksort(Array, Object(Closure)) #4 /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/stylesheet.php(149): Elementor\Stylesheet->add_query_hash('min_laptop') #5 /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/file in /home/customer/www/rangoliayurved.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/breakpoints/manager.php on line 233

i dont know what to do now

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering seems to be related to the Elementor plugin in WordPress.

It indicates a problem with the plugin's breakpoints manager, suggesting that it's trying to access a function on a null object.  This could happen due to various reasons, such as a conflict with other plugins or a problem with the specific template you inserted.

To resolve this, you can try the following steps:

1.**Deactivate Elementor**: Go to your WordPress dashboard, navigate to the "Plugins" section, and deactivate the Elementor plugin. This might temporarily resolve the issue, allowing you to access your website.

2.**Check Template**: Review the template you inserted to ensure there are no errors or missing components that might be causing the problem. Correct any issues and then reactivate Elementor.

3.**Plugin Conflict**: If the issue persists, it could be a conflict with another plugin. Deactivate other plugins one by one to identify if any of them are causing the problem. Once you identify the conflicting plugin, you can seek a solution or an alternative plugin.

4.**Update Elementor**: Ensure that your Elementor plugin is up to date. Sometimes, updating the plugin can resolve compatibility issues.